# How to obtain value within nested Object SWIFT

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to access a value within a nested object. (**Basically an array containing objects, of which one of the objects contains objects as values**)

```
(result, response, error) -> Void in
        if let err = error {
            print("ERROR ---------------------->", err)
        } else if let tempResult = result as? [NSDictionary] {

            print(tempResult.count)

            for details in tempResult {
                print("----------------->")
                print(details["details"]!) //works fine
                print(details["details"]["price"]!) //will not compile
                }
}
```

This  is the compiler warning I was getting

```
print(details["version"]["type"]!) // Type 'Any?' has no subscript members
```

This is the tree structure of the data i am parsing

```
[ 
 { name: 'Mischief',
 price: 790000,
 link: 'xxxxxxx',
 details: 
      { price: '7390000', web: 'link', info: 'details' } },

 { name: 'Ify',
 price: 190000,
 link: 'xxxxxxx',
 details: 
      { price: '690000', web: 'link', info: 'details' } },

 { name: 'Connor',
 price: 980000,
 link: 'xxxxxxx',
 details: 
      { price: '120000', web: 'link', info: 'details' } }
]
```

Comment: Please include error messages directly in the question, not as external links.  It makes it difficult for others who have similar issues to benefit from this question.

Comment: @JoeC sorry cant directly attach images reason being I dont have sufficient **reputation**

Comment: Who said the error message had to be in the form of an image?

Comment: @JoeC oh right! i get what you mean, i will edit the question and type in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, please do not use Foundation collection types. You throw away the type information. Use Swift native types unless you have no choice.

The compiler needs to know the type of all subscripted objects, the value of `details` seems to be `[String:String]`

```
(result, response, error) -> Void in
    if let err = error {
        print("ERROR ---------------------->", err)
    } else if let tempResult = result as? [[String:Any]] {

        print(tempResult.count)

        for anItem in tempResult {
            print("----------------->")
            if let details = anItem["details"] as? [String:String] {
               print(details["price"]!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but i get this compiler warning `Type '(key:string, value: Any)' has no subscript members`

Comment: At what line? The code is Swift 3 related, if you're using Swift 2 replace `Any` with `AnyObject`

Comment: I'm using Swift 3

Comment: HEY!!! Thanks man! it worked. I didnt notice the double square brackets `[[String:Any]]`